# Что такое абсолютная величина для целочисленного типа?

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста написанное ниже.

> Целочисленные типы со знаком имеют большое значение для очень многих алгоритмов, но по абсолютной величине они наполовину меньше своих аналогов без знака. Вот как, например, выглядит число 32 767 типа short в двоичном представлении.
>
> 0111111111111111
>
> Если установить старший разряд этого числа равным 1, чтобы получить значение со знаком, то оно будет интерпретировано как -1, принимая во внимание формат дополнения до двух. Но если объявить его как значение типа
> ushort, то после установки в 1 старшего разряда оно станет равным 65 535."

Comment: Какое именно из утверждений вам непонятно?

Comment: 1)Что такое абсолютная величина? 2)Как понять "будет интерпретировано как -1"  и что такое формат дополнения до двух?

Comment: 1) по модулю 2) 16 двоичных единиц для short это -1 в десятичной системе. Про формат сам не помню. 16 единиц для ushort это 65535.

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, поставьте зеленую галочкв слева от него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> но по абсолютной величине они наполовину меньше своих аналогов без
> знака

Тут явно пропущено слово "максимальной" (абсолютной величине). Числа без знака при использовании того же количества бит позволяют представить в два раза большие числа по абсолютной величине (ну, почти).
Например, два байта со знаком это числа от `-32768` до `32767`, а без знака это от `0` до `65535`. Количество чисел, которые можно представить - одинаковое, а вот абсолютная величина у беззнаковых чисел возможна почти в 2 раза большая.

> Если установить старший разряд этого числа равным 1, чтобы получить
> значение со знаком, то оно будет интерпретировано как -1

Это значит, что битовое значение `1111 1111 1111 1111`, хранимое в памяти, означает как тип `short` число `-1`.

> формат дополнения до двух

Если я ничего не путаю, то это значит, что отрицательные числа из их битового представления можно вычислить как (единичку в начале я убрал - она даёт нам знак, а не само число):

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 -
1000 0000 0000 0000 =
                 -1 (short)
```

Или, если так понятнее:

```
                  1 +
0111 1111 1111 1111 =
1000 0000 0000 0000
```

Т.е. как бы сколько нужно добавить к битовому представлению числа, чтобы все его разряды (кроме старшего - знакового) "стали двойкой" или "переполнились". К двоичному числу `0111 1111 1111 1111` нужно добавить `1`, чтобы все его числовые разряды "дополнились до двух", поэтому это `-1`. Знак числа определяется старшим битом, абсолютное значение для отрицательных чисел - вот этим "дополнением до двух".

```
1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

Знак числа: 0 - положительное, 1 - отрицательное

```
x111 1111 1111 1111
```

Собственно число: положительное - как есть, отрицательное - в виде "дополнения до двух".

Comment: 17 знаков в примере, ноликами не обсчитался?) Или я не понял.

Comment: @aepot Я просто не уверен, что если арифметический пример будет с циклическим переполнением в фиксированных двух байтах, то он станет понятнее неискушённому читателю, чем пример с "расширением" единички в следующий байт )

Comment: @aepot В общем-то вы правы, там же ещё знаковый разряд, переписал примеры и вообще ответ